# Literary techniques involving sound

Tags: literary-techniques

What literary sound device/technique is expressed through the phrase "*sudden departures*", involving the articulation of the words? (alliteration, assonance, sibilance etc.)

Comment: This isn't homework is it? It might be helpful if you could explain the context of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "sound device" I can hear in that phrase is its meter, which is a catalectic dactylic dimeter.  A dactyl is a set of three syllables, the first of which is stressed; in a dimeter pattern, the dactyl occurs twice: DA-da-da DA-da-da.  "SUD-den de-PART-ure" fits that meter, except for missing the final, unstressed syllable; leaving off an unstressed syllable at the start or end of the metric pattern is "catalexis".

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the type of example I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no alliteration or assonance, and just a modicum of sibilance. Alliteration involves the beginnings of adjacent or closely connect words, assonance is repetition of vowel sounds that create an echo effect; and as sibilance refers to a hissing effect (usually achieved with multiple unvoiced *s* sounds — as in the word *susurrus*), and there is only one such sound in your example, I'm not sure what you're going for here? Perhaps if you described the quality you see in *sudden departures* that is noteworthy to you, we might be able to see what you're really asking.

Comment: Thanks for writing. Sorry if I was unclear, but I was referring to any sound device utilized in that phrase; and when making reference to alliteration, sibilance and assonance, I was outlining examples of what I meant by "sound devices".

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think alliteration was completely restricted to the start of words. I think the repeating of the "plosive" "D" sounds Su**DD**en **D**eparture is a form of alliteration too, even though the "D" sounds aren't at the beginning of the word Sudden.
This gives the phrase an almost explosive impact - which perhaps reflects the "Sudden-ness"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "[onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia)", meaning a word that imitates the sound it represents?